# How to write a formula field(date) based on picklist value and date field

Tags: apex

I have a requirement to write a formula field(`Month_year`) based on `status__c`(picklist,have 3 values: **1-This Month, 2-Next month, 3-Lat Month**) and date field.
For Ex:

```
Status=this month and date= 1/1/ 2015
then value in formula field should be update as per mentioned values.
ex:For this month, Month_year= January 2015
for Last Month, Month_year=December 2014
for Next month, month_year=February 2015
```

Any suggestion please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution to your question as per my understanding. I have created 3 cases based on the status and further based on the month values created 12 cases each returning their text values. Hope you find it useful.

```
CASE(Status__c, 
"Last Month", CASE(MONTH(My_Date__c)-1,
    0, "December " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)-1),
    1, "January " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    2, "February " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    3, "March " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    4, "April " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    5, "May " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    6, "June " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    7, "July " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    8, "August " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    9, "September " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    10, "October " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    11, "November " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
"None"), 
"This Month", CASE(MONTH(My_Date__c),
    1, "January " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    2, "February " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    3, "March " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    4, "April " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    5, "May " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    6, "June " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    7, "July " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    8, "August " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    9, "September " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    10, "October " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    11, "November " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    12, "December " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
"None"),
"Next Month",CASE(MONTH(My_Date__c)+1,
    2, "February " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    3, "March " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    4, "April " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    5, "May " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)), 
    6, "June " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    7, "July " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    8, "August " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    9, "September " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    10, "October " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    11, "November " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    12, "December " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)),
    13, "January " + TEXT(year(My_Date__c)+1),
"None"), "None")
```